# Protect my SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I have created an application that use a sql server database.

But the problem is that a user can open sql server management studio and can do anything that I don't like , for example :

1) Can modify values inside tables.

2) can delete records

3) Can see and can get my database structure.....

......

How can I protect my database , so that users can modify this database only inside my application , and can do anything outside my application ? I don't know does exist a way to protect my database with a password or.... ??? for example when I was using Access for database , i have protected Access files with a password , and after only my application can open this database . 
 Is possible to include a protection in the sql server database file ( so even the file is imported to another computer to remain protected ?

Thank you !

---

Updated :
Please let me explain because i have a specific situation :

My application is designated to manage several "office".

In my application folder , i have a empty backup file ( offline)  of my database called "Model". And inside my application a user can create "A new office " and when he do this the application restore a copy of "Model" inside sql server with a specific name (for example "Office1". Another time the user can create another "Office" using again a copy of "Model"

So inside Sql server may be different databases ( all of them with the same structure ) like "Model"

So in this situation how can i Protect my databases and the "Model" .

Because i think  i should apply a Protection" inside the offline backup file "Model" ( if it's possible , all the databases that have created from "Model" will have the protection ) or ??????

What should i do in this case ?

Thank you !

Comment: This topic has been extensively covered here on Stackoverflow. Use the search and read on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can protect a SQL Server database from unwanted intrusions.

You can assign different groups to Database Roles.  If you assign everyone that has access to a DB_DATAREADER role, they can only read the data.

Read more here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Your application will need connect via a role that is DB_DATAWRITER.

Someone in a DB_DATABASEOWNER role, or a SYSADMIN role (these is a server level role), will have full access to all objects in a database by default (unless you revoke these permissions).

Comment: ok , but I can stop sql server service , and after I can copy the mdf file to another pc and I can do what I want.

Comment: @alex anything can easily be broken if a user has higher privileges than the one locking it up wants that user to have.

Comment: @alex: If users can freely access the box where the databases or their backups reside and you want to ensure the physical files become unusable when transferred to a different machine, then perhaps what you want is [database encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Haven't got any personal experience working with it, so can't comment on whether it would be a good idea to go down this road. (Only suggesting it because it seems like the only solution under the circumstances. Personally, I'd look into possibilities to change the circumstances.)

Comment: How can I encrypt the database ?

Comment: @alex that question has been answered here a few times. I would suggest a search.

Comment: I can't find an example similar to my case. So encrypt database and use this from vb.net.If you have a link please show to me. Thank you !

Comment: I suggest you post a new question on this site.  You will reach a wider audience.